# Read logcat continuously in Android app

Tags: android, android-service, logcat

I'm trying to read continuously - which means:

If, for example, I have a process that every few second write something to logcat, I want my app to listen on this logcat, once a new line is added - it will catch it and show it on the screen

I have one activity that every second write a counter to a log:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
        Log.d("bbb", "i= " + i);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);               
    }
};
```

I have a service that is trying to "listen" on "logcat -s bbb", but once the listener started - the app stuck (looks like the app entered an endless loop) and after a few seconds I got a message that the app must be closed.

The listener code is: (the message "start read line" is printed and that's it...)

```
public static void Parse()
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = rt.exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());  
        os.writeBytes("logcat -s bbb");
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    try {
        Log.d("aaa","start read line");
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.d("aaa", "line = " + line);
        }
        Log.d("aaa", "finish");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The service call the function Parse() once.

Someone have any idea what is wrong?

*** EDIT: I found the problem - The command "logcat -s bbb" should be execute from the rt (process = rt.exec("logcat -s bbb")), and we don't need the DataOutputStream)
Thanks!

Comment: just an idea, have you try to logcat -d -> save content -> logcat -c and repeat?

Comment: I do not want to read every second the logcat from scratch, I want to be able to get only the new line that was added...

Comment: @kande Hi, are you solve the issue?